# Overview of "Call collect" EIP-86

Tags: protocol

I read [here](https://www.finder.com.au/ethereum-price-what-casper-update-means) that EIP-86 can allow transactions to be paid for by a contract being called. I understand how child-pays-for-parent works in Bitcoin, but [EIP-86](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/86) does not appear to work at all in the same fashion. I feel like I could spend the time trying to grok the EIP and sort things out rather than skimming it like I just did, but there are a number of things that are unclear to me at first blush. For example, I'm not familiar with Serpent, so I don't know if the example account contract is an entire contract or an entry point for a method -- and, if so, which one; then there's the "(2) and (3) introduce a feature similar to bitcoin's P2SH, allowing users to send funds to addresses" -- but no (2) or (3) near by; I guess that refers to "ring signature mixers" and "custom cryptography".

**Could someone please give a high level overview of how EIP-86 enables the contract to pay for the transaction so that I can go back and follow along in the original text?** What I'm worried about is DoS attack models (the last part about miner strategies alludes to possible attacks) and would like to be able to assess if that's a real problem. No, I'm not trying to attack it, but I'm also not so knowledgeable that I think I can contribute anything of value to the EIP discussion :) Thanks!